# Why do some conditional tags not get rendered in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
@helper MyBody
{
  <div>Hello world!</div>
}
```

**The following works perfectly**

```
@helper MyHelper(Func<HelperResult> myFunc)
{
  <div class="modal-body">
    @(config._html.Raw(myFunc != null ? myFunc().ToHtmlString() : ""));
  </div>
}

@MyHelper(MyBody)
```

and renders:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div>Hello World!</div>
  </div>
```

**The following sometimes works properly**

```
@helper MyHelper(Func<HelperResult> myFunc)
{
  <div class="modal-body">
    @if(myFunc != null)
    {
      myFunc();
    }
  </div>
}

@MyHelper(MyBody)
```

but occasionaly, depending on some still unknown influence, renders:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
```

One piece of code always renders the same, it doesn't switch behavior when refreshing a page. The (large amount of) surrounding code seems to contain the unknown influence.

Can anyone explain why? What can make Razor go wrong that it doesn't render the "Hello World!" DOM element? I'm used to old-school PHP, which has a simple principle: it renders text, and doesn't care about DOM. Razor doesn't work in the same way?

An article describing the deep internals of the Razor engine would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? From reading what you have it sounds like you potentially should be using a PartialView rather than trying to invoke a function from Razor.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-4

Comment: MyFunc is not null but returns an empty result. That explains it.

Comment: @Oliver I'd like to keep the inserted code inline. You need to put the declaration of a PartialView in a separate file? Interesting concept though, thanks!

Comment: @JotaBe Nope, I put a breakpoint and stepped through the code, myFunc definitely returns the proper html.

Comment: Please, try two things: 1) include `@Html.Raw("Hello!");` 2) include `@Html.Raw(myFunc());` in your conditional block, and outside it, and let me know the result.

Comment: @JotaBe I can't get it to break anymore! The code that 'sometimes worked properly' now always does its job. The only cause I think of is that a full clean and rebuild fixed it.

Comment: Or our beautiful friend: the cache! When in doubt you can use a browser that avoids caching. For example, I use Chrome. If you open the dev tools, there is an option (configuration, general, 1st option) that allows to avoid caching whenever this dev tools are open. Remember that the app can also cache in some circumstances.